# Equivalent condition to boundedness of a linear operator

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory

I have to prove the following statement:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces over $\mathbb{K}$ and $T:X\to Y$ a linear operator. Prove that $T$ is bounded iff $\sum_{n=1}^\infty T(x_n)$ converges for all sequences $\{x_n\}$ for which $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges absolutely.

I have been stuck on this problem for days, yet I feel I'm really close to solving it. Any hint, idea or advice would be appreciated. I haven't been able to prove any of the implications, but this is what I have right now:

For the $(\implies)$ direction, assume that $T$ is bounded, and let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges absolutely. I'm trying to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty T(x_n)$ converges on two steps. First I prove that the sequence $\{S_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ where

$$
S_k=\sum_{n=1}^kT(x_n)
$$

is Cauchy. This is easy to show using the boundedness and linearity of $T$, and the fact that $\{\sum_{n=1}^k ||x_n||\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy, because it converges. Then I would like to prove that the sequence $\{S_k\}$ has a convergent subsequence, as that would imply the result. However, I don't know how to show this. The only idea I had was to prove and use this statement:

> If $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence on a normed space $X$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges absolutely, then there exists a sequence $\{n_k\}$ of positive integers such that the sequence $\{\sum_{n=1}^{n_k} x_n\}_{k=1}^\infty$ converges.

as the continuity and linearity of $T$ would then imply what I want. However, I don't think that statement is true, as it would then imply that every normed space is Banach, which is obviously not true. So I have no idea on how to proceed now. In general I am having trouble to prove the convergence of almost anything, any advice for that would be really helpful.

For the ($\impliedby$) direction, I am trying to use the sequential criterion for continuity to prove that $T$ is continuous, and since $T$ is linear that would prove that $T$ is bounded. Let $a\in X$ and $\{x_n\}$ a sequence in $X$ that converges to $a$. I want to prove that $T(x_n)\to T(a)$. I trying to use the same steps as in the other implication, i.e. I need to show that $\{T(x_n)\}$ is Cauchy and has a subsequence that converges to $T(a)$. Here however, I managed to show the existence of a convergent subsequence, but I don't see how to show that the sequence is Cauchy. To see that it has a subsequence convergent to $T(a)$, notice the following:

As $x_n\to a$, for each $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ there exists an $n_k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that

$$
||x_{n_k}-a||<\dfrac{1}{2^k}
$$

And since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}$ converges, we have that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty||x_{n_k}-a||$ converges. By hypothesis, this implies that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty T(x_{n_k}-a)$ converges, and from here we get that $||T(x_{n_k})-T(a)||=||T(x_{n_k}-a)||\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$, and as such $T(x_{n_k})\to T(a)$.

If now I manage to prove that $\{T(x_n)\}$ is Cauchy, I would get the result. However I have no idea on how to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help you could give me!

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ is bounded (and linear), and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges to $x$ (no need for absolutely) then
$$T(x) = T\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n\right) = T\left(\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N x_n\right) = \lim_{N \to \infty} T\left(\sum_{n=1}^N x_n\right) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N T(x_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty T(x_n).$$
That's the "easy" direction ($\implies$).

As for ($\impliedby$), your partial result could actually be used to get you the full way, except that it tacitly assumes completeness. Just showing that $\sum \|x_{n_k} - a\|$ is finite doesn't actually prove $\sum (x_{n_k} - a)$ converges! Indeed, this implication is equivalent to the domain being complete.

The key observation is that, for linear operators, dealing with sequences is very similar to dealing with series. For a sequence $y_n \to y$, we can define $x_n = y_{n+1} - y_n$, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n = y - y_1$. This way, we can turn a convergent sequence into a convergent (telescoping) series.

The big wrinkle here is that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ may not converge absolutely. To correct this, we can take a subsequence $y_{n_m}$ such that $\|y_{n_m} - y\| < \frac{1}{2^m}$. Then,
$$\|y_{n_{m+1}} - y_{n_m}\| \le \|y_{n_{m+1}} - y\| + \|y_{n_m} - y\| < \frac{1}{2^{m+1}} + \frac{1}{2^m} = \frac{3}{2^{m+1}}.$$
If we let $x_m = y_{n_{m+1}} - y_{n_m}$, then $\sum x_m$ converges absolutely to $y - y_{n_1}$. Using the condition on $T$, this means
$$T(y) -T(y_{n_1}) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty T(x_m) = \lim_{M \to \infty} \sum_{m=1}^M (T(y_{n_{m+1}}) - T(y_{n_m})) = \lim_{M \to \infty} (T(y_{n_{M+1}}) - T(y_{n_1})),$$
hence
$$T(y) = \lim_{M \to \infty}T(y_{n_{M+1}}).$$
This puts us in a similar position to where your solution took us. But, we can now use another auxiliary result to get us to the finish line:

> Suppose $x_n$ is a sequence in a normed linear space (or indeed metric space). Further, suppose we have a fixed point $x$ and $x_n$ has the property that, given any subsequence $x_{n_m}$, there exists a (sub)subsequence $x_{n_{m_k}}$ converging to $x$. Then $x_n \to x$.

The proof is not too hard. If $x_n$ does not converge to $x$, then a subsequence must stay some $\varepsilon > 0$ distance away from $x$. Such a subsequence has no (sub)subsequences that converge to $x$.

Now, we can apply the above result to $T(y_n)$. Note that any subsequence $T(y_{n_m})$ corresponds to a subsequence $y_{n_m}$ of $y_n$. Such a subsequence still converges to $y$, so by the previous working, a (sub)subsequence $y_{n_{m_k}}$ exists such that
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} T(y_{n_{m_k}}) = T(y).$$
By the stated result, this implies $T(y_n) \to T(y)$ as well, hence $T$ is continuous (and bounded).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have some further questions:

For the $(\implies)$, why do you say that the series $\sum x_n$ converges? What we have by hypothesis is that it converges absolutely, and since $X$ is not necessarily complete I think that wouldn't imply the convergence of the series.

For the $(\impliedby)$, I don't see where in my argument for the existence of a convergent subsequence I assume completeness of the domain. I thought I was just using the hypothesis. Your argument for this part is really cool tho and I didn't know that last auxiliary result you shared.

Comment: @Kerd I took absolute convergence to mean that the series converges, and that the series of norms converges too. To be honest, I'm not used to considering absolute convergence outside of complete spaces (I don't think it's a common consideration), but that's the definition that makes the most intuitive sense to me. If your lecturer/book has a different definition, then unfortunately my answer will not be of much help to you. My personal suspicion is that the spaces were intended to be complete, thus this debate was supposed to be avoided.

Comment: @Kerd As for your other question, this once again relates to our difference in definition of absolute convergence. You proved the series of norms converges. In a complete space, this proves the series converges too, but this isn't necessarily true in an incomplete space. According to my definition, that the series and the series of norms both converge, you haven't shown that the series is convergent.